# ant not working on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, java, compiling

I have installed ant on my ubuntu 12.10. When i try to compile a java project with build.xml, i get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ant: 1: eval: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string


ls -lrt /usr/bin/ant
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 May 18  2012 /usr/bin/ant -> ../share/ant/bin/ant
```

if i use `\ant` is works.

```
dpkg -l ant
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-=========================================================
ii  ant                        1.8.2-4build2      all                Java based build tool like make
```

Please help

Comment: How did you install ant? Using the Ubuntu package I suppose? Please show the output of `dpkg -l ant` run from a terminal in your question. To me this looks like an issue with ant itself, not the build file itself, because the error message shows line 1 of /usr/bin/ant to be the fault.

Comment: If ant is installed properly(and at first glance, it looks like it has), this would be a problem with your code, specifically. You can certainly post your code here for us to look at, but this question might be better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/?as=1)

Comment: dpkg -l ant

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-=========================================================
ii  ant                        1.8.2-4build2      all                Java based build tool like make

Comment: @Vivek Please **edit** your question to provide more details. It's how this site works (comments are not fit for that as you see!). I suspect now that you've set up an alias in your shell. Could you try invoking ant with a backslash prepended, e.g. `\ant build.xml`? That would disable any aliases configured. Also, what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/ant`? This should be a symbolic link to `../share/ant/bin/ant`. If not, you've changed something on your system and you need to tell us what you did.

Comment: @gertvdijk- \ant is working :-)

Comment: @Vivek Good to hear that. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

As appeared [in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311708/ant-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-10#comment393523_311708), there's a Bash alias set for `ant` which overrides the call to the regular `ant` in `PATH`, because running ant with a backslash prepended (`\ant`) does work.

*This alias setting not happen automatically - you have set this yourself somehow.*

Run

```
alias
```

to see what aliases you have defined more on your system. Locate the line in any of the scripts initializing your shell to disable this. Files like

- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/envrionment`

are the ones to check. Use for example

```
grep -n ant ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/environment
```

to locate the file and line number. Remove the line, then log out and log back in.

Comment: I checked all the files but could not find any wrong alias to ant. Any other hint to track this?

Comment: @Vivek This is a needle in a haystack. Can you create a (temporary) other user and while logged in as the other user try it again? Report back if that works or not - if so, then that would limit the scope to user files.